# Displaying String of an Object in an ArrayList<Object> in a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

So I've run into a problem with my code.

First of all, I've got an `ArrayList` with objects added to it:

```
cellRoomObjects = new ArrayList<>();
RoomObjects door = new RoomObjects("Door" , 1 , true);
RoomObjects oilLamp = new RoomObjects("Oil lamp", 2 , true);
RoomObjects chest = new RoomObjects("Chest" , 3 , true);
RoomObjects wallCarving = new RoomObjects("Wall Carving", 4 , false);
cellRoomObjects.add(door);
cellRoomObjects.add(oilLamp);
cellRoomObjects.add(chest);
cellRoomObjects.add(wallCarving);
```

Second, I got a `JComboBox`, that takes a `String[]` array as input:

```
String[] objectStrings = { "Bookcase", "Chest", "Door", "Safe",
            "Comfortable chair" };

JComboBox objectList = new JComboBox(objectStrings);
```

Now I would like my `JComboBox` to show the name (`"Door"`, `"Oil Lamp"`, `"Chest"` and `"Wall Carving"`) of each Object of my `ArrayList<RoomObjects>`'s String,
 but I'm not sure how to do this. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just named variables as I like, u can rename,

```
public class CellRoomObject {

    String itemName;
    int itemNumber;
    boolean ok;

    public CellRoomObject(String itemName, int itemNumber, boolean ok) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
        this.ok = ok;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.itemName;
    }


}
```

Now your ArrayList

```
// create a JCOMBOBOx named  say myCombobox
```

public class MyFrame  extends JFrame{

```
 public MyFrame() {

       setTitle("example");
       setSize(300, 200);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
       JComboBox myBox=new JComboBox();
       ArrayList<CellRoomObject> cellRoomObjects =new ArrayList<CellRoomObject>();
        CellRoomObject c1=new CellRoomObject("Door" , 1 , true);
         CellRoomObject c2=new CellRoomObject("Oil lamp", 2 , true);
          CellRoomObject c3=new CellRoomObject("Chest" , 3 , true);
          cellRoomObjects.add(c1);
           cellRoomObjects.add(c2);
           cellRoomObjects.add(c3);
        DefaultComboBoxModel dcbm =new DefaultComboBoxModel(cellRoomObjects.toArray());
        myBox.setModel(dcbm);
        this.add(myBox);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyFrame ex = new MyFrame();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Try this(Do necessary imports)

Comment: I tried the above, but I get a nullPointerException at the line:  DefaultComboBoxModel dcbm =new DefaultComboBoxModel(cellRoomObjects.toArray());

Comment: I just copy pasted ur JComboBox  myBox=new JComboBox(); and DefaultComboBoxModel dcbm =new DefaultComboBoxModel(cellRoomObjects.toArray());
        myBox.setModel(dcbm); and put the String toString method in my RoomObjects class

Comment: Uhh.. its a very big, and very confusing gui code at the moment, on 800 lines, but I can try to cut it down to what you need to see on a paste bin :S

Comment: Oh I got it fixed now - Thanks for your help, I was just being stupid - I actually didn't ran the method, that adds stuff in my arraylist, and thats why it got a null pointer exception - You helped me greatly tho, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Make the

```
cellRoomObjects = new Vector();
```

Override toString() method of RoomObjects to return only the name (or title or whatever the String field)

Create the JComboBox(cellRoomObjects );

Comment: I can see 2 people upvoted this, and it looks quite easy - Do I just add it to the method or?

Comment: I tried putting cellRoomObjects = new Vector(); in both a method which didn't work, and in an attributem wich didn't work either, as it says: ArrayList<RoomObject> cannot be converted to Vector

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to get each string and store them in an array:
for example something like this:

```
String[] myNames=new String[cellRoomObjects.size()];
int i= 0;
for(RoomObjects r : cellRoomObjects ){
   myName[i]=r.getName() //assuming there is a method that gets name in RoomObjects that returns  the string u want
   i++
}
```